# Impersonate User On The Current Thread

Tags: java

I'd like to create a Java function that, given a username and password, elevates the associated thread / process 's security context (in Windows) such that other functions can perform e.g. administrative tasks BUT using the original user's context / environment i.e. similar to

```
runas.exe /env /u:... [/p:...] java.exe ...
```

but on the current thread / process.

The closest I've got was by investigating PriviledgedActions, but the classes involved and their interconnections became rather bewildering.
Could someone provide me with some pointers to achieve the above?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: As you want to perform admin tasks, I guess your code is not portable anymore. If so, you could rely on authentication mechanisms provided by the OS such as runas or sudo. If not, I got no idea, I can't remember of anything in the jdk that is close to the concept of user/permissions related to the OS in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PrivilegedAction` won't work for this, unfortunately. If you need to access files, [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) can do so as any user. Active Directory access through JNDI is possible, but for other things you will probably need to break out to native code using JNI.